# Xamarin xaml binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to bind my xaml to a property in my view model, but it doesn't work as I expected.

The following code works, but it seems to create a new instance of the mainwindowviewmodel object which will result in problem.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Test}" >
    <Label.BindingContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Label.BindingContext>
</Label>
```

The following doesn't work at all.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path=Test}" >
</Label>
```

I've the property Test in my view model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure to set the `DataContext` of the *View* to an instance of the model (`local:MainWindowViewModel)` to make the second code snippet work.

Comment: Where are you setting the `DataContext` of the View? Directly in the XAML or in code behind?

Comment: @Nkosi You're right, I forgot it. Adding BindingContext helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the `BindingContext` of the *View* to an instance of the model (`MainWindowViewModel)` to make the second code snippet work.

For example in the constructor of the view's code behind

```cs
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponents();
    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Or directly in the View

```xml
<MainWindow.BindingContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</MainWindow.BindingContext>
```

The both above are technically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! However, it's called BindingContext in Xamarin.

Comment: @random thank you for the correction. Had WPF on the brain. Updated answer to match. Glad it helped.